# Is there a way to see which views/blocks part of a site

Tags: drupal-7

Ive never worked with Drupal before so I apologize if this is a bad question.

I'm helping a non profit out with updating an issue they have on their drupal site.  They are using a bootstrap template and I see the issue is that a div.row has an extra end tag before the second col, thus rendering the second col on the next row.

I know thats the issue but I have absolutely no idea what block or view is causing the issue.  I can click on the top right of the individual blocks contained within the cols and "edit view" or "configure block" but when I go to edit them it takes me to that individual item when I need to edit the parent container for that item.

Is there an easy way to do find the parent row for these blocks so that I can fix the premature ending div for the row?